# Подскажите можно ли разобрать $_REQEST, если заранее не известно имя ключа

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Клиент(JS) имеет несколько методов, которые он может использовать при отправке на сервер AJAXом('method='+ methodValue).

Сервер(PHP) в свою очередь обрабатывает $_REQEST(т.к данные могут быть пересланы и POST методом и GET). В зависимости от 'method'а скрипт должен выполнять тот или иной код.

Вопрос: Как организовать проверку $_REQEST на наличие 'method'а, если за ранее не известно какой 'method' будет использован?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `call_user_func` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php#refsect1-function.call-user-func-examples   и пример №4 .......`call_user_func(array('className', 'methodName'));`  - вызывает метод `methodName` в классе `className` .....параметры тоже можно передавать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имя метода передаётся в параметре method, то нужно проверить наличие указанного метода в классе и, если он есть, вызвать его

```
class Action
{
    public function method1($arg)
    {
        echo 'method1:'.$arg;
    }

    public function method2($arg)
    {
        echo 'method2:'.$arg;
    }
}

$act = new Action();

if (isset($_REQUEST['method']) && method_exists($act, $_REQUEST['method']))
{
    $act->{$_REQUEST['method']}('value');
}
```